How to compute a 3D morton code from 3 128bit values?
I want to encode a position (x_u128,y_u128,z_u128) into one 3D morton code.
Therefore I chose the bit interleaving/"magic bits" method (also mentioned here for 3x21bit inputs 3d_morton_interleave ).
From my understanding each 128 bit value is spread by the shifting and bitmasking to result in a spreaded 3 * 128bits = 384 bits value:
(128bits,128bits,128bits) --> (384bits,384bits,384bits)
each interleaved by 2 zeros (like 0b..001000001001001 for the input 0b..0010111)
Those 3 spread values then need to be combined to the final morton code:
spread(x) | spread(y)<<1 | spread(z) << 2
Which is then 384bits large, correct?
I've then tried to expand the bitmasks to fit the 128bit input (e.g. add a first shift by 64 bits and the mask_1 and it didn't interleave as expected.
What's wrong?
Here's my code (most important part at the bottom of the spread(..) function):
use num::BigUint;
use num::One;

pub fn spread(v: u128) -> BigUint {
    //bitmask ... 32 ones 64 zeros 32 ones
    let mut mask_1 = BigUint::from(0x0000000000000000ffffffff00000000_u128);
    mask_1 <<= 128;
    mask_1 += 0x00000000ffffffff0000000000000000_u128;
    mask_1 <<= 128;
    mask_1 += 0xffffffff0000000000000000ffffffff_u128;

    //bitmask 0b...11111111 11111111 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111
    let mut mask_2 = BigUint::from(0x00000000ffff00000000ffff00000000_u128);
    mask_2 <<= 128;
    mask_2 += 0xffff00000000ffff00000000ffff0000_u128;
    mask_2 <<= 128;
    mask_2 += 0x0000ffff00000000ffff00000000ffff_u128;

    //bitmask 0b...11111111 00000000 00000000 11111111
     let mut mask_3 = BigUint::from(0x0000ff0000ff0000ff0000ff0000ff00_u128);
    mask_3 <<= 128;
    mask_3 += 0x00ff0000ff0000ff0000ff0000ff0000_u128;
    mask_3 <<= 128;
    mask_3 += 0xff0000ff0000ff0000ff0000ff0000ff_u128;

    //bitmask 0b...1111000000001111000000001111
    let mut mask_4 = BigUint::from(0x00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00_u128);
    mask_4 <<= 128;
    mask_4 += 0xf00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f0_u128;
    mask_4 <<= 128;
    mask_4 += 0x0f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f00f_u128;

    //bitmask 0b...11000011000011
    let mut mask_5 = BigUint::from(0x0c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c_u128);
    mask_5 <<= 128;
    mask_5 += 0x30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30_u128;
    mask_5 <<= 128;
    mask_5 += 0xc30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c30c3_u128;

    //bitmask 0b...1001001001
    let mut mask_6 = BigUint::from(0x14924924924924924924924924924924_u128);
    mask_6 <<= 128;
    mask_6 += 0x92492492492492492492492492492492_u128;
    mask_6 <<= 128;
    mask_6 += 0x49249249249249249249249249249249_u128;

    let mut value = BigUint::from(v);
    value = (value.clone() | (value << 64)) & mask_1;
    value = (value.clone() | (value << 32)) & mask_2;
    value = (value.clone() | (value << 16)) & mask_3;
    value = (value.clone() | (value << 8)) & mask_4;
    value = (value.clone() | (value << 4)) & mask_5;
    value = (value.clone() | (value << 2)) & mask_6;
    return value;
}

pub fn combine_spread(x_spread: BigUint, y_spread: BigUint, z_spread: BigUint) -> BigUint {

    let result = x_spread | y_spread << 1 | z_spread << 2;

    return result;
}



using a bigint type for a fixed int thing like this is vastly inefficient. There are PDEP instruction in modern x86 that does this very efficiently and you can call it with the  core::arch::x86_64::_pdep_u64 intrinsic or safe_arch::population_deposit_u64, and if it's not available there are better solutions like using SIMD: How to do bit striping

@phuclv Thank you, but I definately need a bigger data type, since the 3 inputs having 128 bits each need to be combined. (i.e. 384 bits right?!)
From my rough understanding of your mentioned instructions, they are only capable of handling u64 variables. Or if I'm wrong, please give a short example, which part of the code you would change to your mentioned instructions.

@Heavypilgrim that just means that you need to use that operation multiple times

@Heavypilgrim extending the operation to 128 bit is just trivial. You just need a custom 128-bit int type with some necessary operators, not an arbitrary-precision type. And rust even has u128 so just a write pdep_u128 -> u128 yourself which is basically a few lines to call pdep_u64
